# How to perform nested routes in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a controller (articles).

It performs routes: `/articles`, `/articles/:id`  and this is it.

I need also the following routes - `/articles/creator/:creatorId`, `/articles/:id/like`, `/articles/:id/unlike`, `/articles/:id/comment` and so on.

Whether I need static path or action it is nested and its not working.

Partial solution for me - Controller (articles), Controller (articles/creator), Controller (articles/like), Controller (articles/unlike).

But this is a dumb solution and the concept of paths and actions is lost.

Is there an elegant solution to fix this? And how to achieve this in best way?

The code:

```
@Controller('articles')
class ArticlesController{

@Get(':articleId')
getById(@Param('articleId') articleId){}

@Post(':articleId/like)
like(@Param('articleId') articleId){}

@Get('creator/:creatorId')
getByCreator(@Param('creatorId') creatorId:string){}

}
```

Comment: Please also include the relevant parts of your code in your question. (In this case your controller.) It makes answering your question easier. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you have a dynamic route parameter for an article id, you can have one for an action as well:

```
@Controller('articles')
export class ArticlesController {

  @Get(':id/:action')
  findAll(@Param('id') id, @Param('action') action) {
    return `You chose ${action} for article ${id}`;
  }
```